# How to count ";" in line

Tags: java

I want to count ";" in line from text file.

Ex. In my text file

- case 1: int a; int b;
- case 2: int c;
- case 3: int x; int y; int z;

My expected out put is

- line 1 have 2 ";" in line
- line 2 have 1 ";" in line
- line 3 have 3 ";" in line

My code

```
Scanner (input);

while(in.hasNext()){

            String line = in.nextLine();
            in.hasNextLine();
            LOC++;
            if (line.length() >0){
                k = -1;

                if(line.indexOf(";") != 1){
                    while(true){
                        k = line.indexOf(";");
                        if(k<0)break;
                        cCommand++;
                    }

                }

            }
        }

System.out.println(output);
```

**Thank you for your answering.**

Comment: So what it the problem with your code ? What happens when your run it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
int c=0;
for(char ch : line.toCharArray())
{
    if(ch==';') c++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

A concise (but inefficient) approach would be to strip out everything except `;` from the string, and then use the length:

```
int numSemicolons = str.replaceAll("[^;]", "").length();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the whole input from the file in a String object
and can use **regex or split(";")** method to get the no. of any pattern(e.g. size of array in case of split()) in that.

If only total no of pattern required or use it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringUtils` from Apache [Common Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("case 3: int x; int y; int z;", ";");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use commons.utils.FileUtils and StringUtils, something like this:

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file, "UTF-8");
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
    String line = it.nextLine();
    int countThe = StringUtils.countMatches(line, ";");
    }
} finally {
    it.close();
}
```